# Number $e(n)$ of trees with $n+1$ unlabeled vertices $n$ labeled edges

Tags: combinatorics, problem-solving

How do I find the number $e(n)$ of trees with $n+1$unlabeled vertices $n$ labeled edges.

We're suppose to give a simple bijective proof, I guess?

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  Given an edge labeled tree $T$ with $n$ edges, choose a vertex of $T$ in $n+1$ ways and label it $0$.  Then "push" each edge label to the vertex of that edge farthest from $0$.

Comment: Much thankful for your help!